# How to Deserialize JSON data in c# and get values from that

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4, serialization

I have serialized my mvc form and now wants to deserialize it in c#.Please help me to tackle this issue.Following is my code of frontend

```
<input type="search" id="txtsearch">
<input type="button" id="btnsearch" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        DrawTable(0);

        $('#btnsearch').click(function (e) {

            var searchname = $('#txtsearch').val();
            var form = $('form').serialize();
            //var form = $(this).serializeArray();

            DrawTable(form);

        });



</script>
```

and following is the method where i want to get values from serialized data by deserializing

```
public JsonResult GetAllCustomers(string sEcho, string sColumns, int iDisplayStart, int iDisplayLength, string sSearch, int iSortCol_0, string sSortDir_0, string filters, int UserId = 0,string form="") {
    string sortDirection = sSortDir_0;
    DataTableGridModel resultModel = new Logic(x,y ).GetCustomersForGrid(sEcho, sColumns, iDisplayStart, iDisplayLength, sSearch, iSortCol_0, sSortDir_0, UserId);
    return Json(resultModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure. But your client code calls `"@Url.Action("GetAllCustomers", "Customer")",` without any parameters.. How do you want to have the values in your controller acrtion `sEcho`, `sColumns` etc?

Comment: @CSharper values are coming from Customer Controller for these...but the problem is that how can get json converted data at backend ?

Comment: which data you mean? actually you have only a `get` method here, without a post.. where do you want to deserialize something?

Comment: @CSharper simply problem is that how to serialize data...currently my data is not correctly serializing

Comment: Than I would recommand anyway the https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/ to serializing and deserializing.

Comment: Guys, if any of you have insight into why my answer below got down-voted, I'd love to hear why, It is a solution I have found handy for processing form data, so...

Answer (score 0):

Use [Newtonsoft.Json.dll](http://www.dllme.com/dll/files/newtonsoft_json_dll.html) for serialization and deserialization of json data in C#

Comment: how can i deserialiuze using this dll

Answer (score 0):

Create below methods using Newtonsoft.Json.dll and invoke deserialize method by passing json data in string format.

```
private static JsonSerializerSettings CreateSettings()
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

        settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        settings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat;

        return settings;
    }

private static Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer CreateSerializer()
    {
        var settings = CreateSettings();

        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Create(settings);
    }

public T Deserialize<T>(object target)
    {
        if (target == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("target");
        }

        var result = default(T);
        var json = target as string;

        if (json != null)
        {
            var serializer = CreateSerializer();

            using (var stringReader = new StringReader(json))
            {
                using (JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader))
                {
                    result = serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**1).ENCODE FORM AS JSON STRING ON CLIENT**

```
//in javascript, serialize the form to JSON:
// -- this will only work if all elements on the form have a name attribute  -
var stringToReturnToServer = JSON.stringify($('form').serializeArray());
```

**2). DECODE JSON STRING TO DICTIONARY, SO YOU CAN RETRIEVE ELEMENT BY NAME**
Server-side, you'll be dealing with a string containing JSON array of objects that each have two properties, name and value. This translates nicely to a C# `Dictionary<string,string>`

```
   using Newtonsoft.Json;

    private class FormField
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string a { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public string b { get; set; }

    }

    private void ReadFormData(string sFormData)
    {
            //this will throw if you give two form fields the same name in your HTML.
            Dictionary<string,string> asFormData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FormField>>(sFormData).ToDictionary(x => x.a, x => x.b);


           //VALUES OF FORM ELEMENTS NOW ACCESSIBLE BY NAME IN DICTIONARY 
           string sSearchText = asFormData["txtsearch"];
}
```

...the code here is limited to serialzing and deserializing, you'll need to GET or POST the actual JSON string back to the server.

Comment: Hi, someone down-voted my answer, and I don't understand why.  Any advice here would be appreciated.